How to troubleshoot this error - "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."
I am developing a chrome extension to provide time stamps to all youtube videos, and it keeps giving me this error - "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.", I have just started building it,
here's my background.js file
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, tab) => {
  if (tab.url && tab.url.includes("youtube.com/watch")) {
    const queryParameters = tab.url.split("?")[1];
    const urlParameters = new URLSearchParams(queryParameters);

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, {
      type: "NEW",
      videoId: urlParameters.get("v"),
    });
  }
});

and here's my contentScript.js
(() => {
    let youtubeLeftControls, youtubePlayer;
    let currentVideo = "";

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((obj, sender, response) => {
        const {type, value, videoId} = obj;
        if(type === "NEW")
        {
            currentVideo = videoId;
            newVideoLoaded();
        }
    });
    
}) ();


and lastly my manifest.json
{
    "name": "YT Saver",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "Saving timestamps in YT videos",
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],
    "host_permissions": ["https://*.youtube.com/*"],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/*"],
        "js": ["contentScript.js"]
      }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      {
        "resources": [
          "assets/bookmark.png",
          "assets/play.png",
          "assets/delete.png",
          "assets/save.png"
        ],
        "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/*"]
      }
    ],
    "action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "assets/ext-icon.png",
        "24": "assets/ext-icon.png",
        "32": "assets/ext-icon.png"
      },
      "default_title": "YT Saver",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 3
}


I tried to make sure I was linking my content scripts correctly in manifest.json file, I reloaded the chrome extension page and the files, I have tried deleting the entire package, reloading it. It did not make a difference yet. I have tried approaches from other posts, but none have worked yet. Any suggestions would be helpful thanks!

You need to re-inject declared content_scripts after reloading/installing the extension in Chrome.

To make sure chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener() is called correctly, insert a console.log() immediately before it.
